# How to save uploaded image to Model in Django? All fields except the image field is getting saved to Model

Tags: python, django

HTML code:

```html
<div class="section-top-border" style=" margin-left : 500px ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
            <h3 class="mb-30 title_color" style="margin-left : 400px ">Add Products to Sell</h3>
            <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="mt-10">
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Name'"
                     required class="single-input">
                </div>
                <div class="mt-10">
                    <input type="email" name="email_address" placeholder="Email address" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Email address'"
                     required class="single-input">
                </div>
                <div class="mt-10">
                    <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Address'"
                     required class="single-input">
                </div>
                <div class="mt-10">
                    <input type="number" name="contact_number" placeholder="Contact Number" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Contact Number'"
                     required class="single-input">
                </div>
                <div class="mt-10">
                    <div class="form-select" id="default-select" >
                        <select  name="product_category">
                            <option value="1">Product Category</option>
                            <option value="Home Decor">Home Decor</option>
                            <option value="Paintings">Paintings</option>
                            <option value="Jewellary">Jewellary</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-10">
                    <div class="form-select" id="default-select2" >
                        <select  name="product_sub_category">
                            <option value="1">Product Sub-Category</option>
                            <option value="Wall-Hangings">Wall-Hangings</option>
                            <option value="Flower-Vases">Flower-Vases</option>
                            <option value="Oil-Paintings">Oil-Paintings</option>
                            <option value="Glass-Paintings">Glass-Paintings</option>
                            <option value="Earrings">Earrings</option>
                            <option value="Necklaces">Necklaces</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mt-10">
                    <input type="text" name="product_name" placeholder="Product Name" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Product Name'"
                     required class="single-input">
                </div>

                <div class="mt-10">
                    <textarea class="single-textarea" name="product_description" placeholder="Product Description" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Product Description'"
                     required></textarea>
                </div>
                    <div class="mt-10">
                    <input type="file" name="product_image" placeholder="Product Image" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Product Image'"
                     required class="single-input">
                    </div>
                <div class="mt-10">
                    <input type="text" name="product_price" placeholder="Product Price" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Product Price'"
                     required class="single-input">
                </div><br><br><br>
                <!--<button type="submit" value="submit" class="main_btn"><a href="{% url 'index' %}">SUBMIT FOR APPROVAL</a></button>-->
                <!--<a class="main_btn" href="{% url 'index' %}">SUBMIT FOR APPROVAL</a>-->
                <button type="submit" class="main_btn">SUBMIT FOR APPROVAL</button>
                <br><br><br>
                <!--<button type="submit" style=" padding : 10px ; margin-left : 410px;"><a href="">SUBMIT FOR APPROVAL</a></button>-->
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

VIEWS.py

```py
def startselling(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email_address = request.POST.get('email_address')
        address = request.POST.get('address')
        contact_number = request.POST.get('contact_number')
        product_category = request.POST.get('product_category')
        product_sub_category = request.POST.get('product_sub_category')
        product_name = request.POST.get('product_name')
        product_description = request.POST.get('product_description')
        product_image = request.POST.get('product_image')
        product_price = request.POST.get('product_price')
        # print(contact_number)
        products = AddProducts()
        products.name = name
        products.email_address = email_address
        products.address = address
        products.contact_number = contact_number
        products.product_category = product_category
        products.product_sub_category = product_sub_category
        products.product_name = product_name
        products.product_description = product_description
        products.product_image = product_image
        products.product_price = product_price
        products.save()
        return redirect('/index')
    return render(request, 'app1/start-selling.html')
```

Attaching the complete code written in `models.py` (for creating the model `AddProducts`), `startselling.html` (the HTML page for the form) and `views.py` (the logic to save data to model on clicking submit).
The HTML page belongs to a template and I edited it according to my need.
`Form.py` is not done for this.
Even without form data is beging saved to model except for the image.
Kindly suggest how to save uploaded image to model

MODELS.py:

```py
class AddProducts(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40,default="")
    email_address = models.EmailField(default="")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="")
    contact_number = models.CharField(max_length=20,default="")
    product_category = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
    product_sub_category = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
    product_description = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
    product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="documents/")
    product_price = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "AddProducts"
```

Comment: Please show your relevant settings, e.g. `MEDIA_URL`, `MEDIA_ROOT`

Answer (score 0):

this is the snippet from one of my project i hope it will also work for you

or follow this amazing youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FdVuKt_iuSI&list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p&index=8

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
```